# Nginx: "unknown directive "push_stream_shared_memory_size" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/push.conf:3"

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, nginx

Не могу перезапусить nginx. Выдает:

```
[....] Restarting nginx: nginxnginx: [emerg] unknown directive "push_stream_shared_memory_size" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/push.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

nginx -V:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.1
built by gcc 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_spdy_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' --with-ipv6
```

Comment: Вероятно модуль который поддерживает данную директиву не стоит

Answer (score 2):

Для использования этой директивы необходим модуль **nginx-push-stream-module**. Он не входит в стандартную комплектацию nginx'а и доступен на [GitHub'е](https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module). Его установка и настройка описаны [здесь](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/push_stream/).